# include_in_all setting in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

According to Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html/) it is possible to exclude a field from *_all* field using *include_in_all* setting (set to *false*). I need to exclude a field from *_all* and I'm using spring data elasticsearch do define my mappings. I haven't found a way to do it this way.

Is this possible using spring data elasticsearch annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spring Data Elasticsearch cannot do this thing. The improvement request is already a year old, but its priority is minor, so there is no hope for now:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-226

In my last project I had to do a lot of simple searches (instead of one by "_all" fields, I used 1 search per each field), and then I united all the results. I assume that there is no nice solve for that problem by Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the mapping of your type into a json file. Then you add the '"include_in_all": false' to the field you want to exclude. This should look something like this.

```
{
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "excludedField": {
        "type": "text",
        "include_in_all": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you load the file using your favorite JSON reader, parse it as a string and change your mapping with the elasticsearch api .

```
client.admin().indices()
      .preparePutMapping("my_index")
      .setType("my_type")
      .setSource(loadedFileString)
      .get();
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed you wanted to use annotations for it. Maybe the @Field annotation has a parameter for it? I'm sorry, I have no experience with the annotations.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't. Annotations are easier and less error-prone which is why I prefer them but I may not have a choice but follow your advice. Although this I think will entail rewriting all the mappings from annotations to json, as it's probably not possible to use them together. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You dont need to rewrite the mappings, you can just check them on your index and copy paste them. Yeah I guess the api is always a bit behind, so who knows when the feature is added.